# How to initialise a class with static members in Jasmine

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, jasmine, ionic3

I have an Angular application (Ionic/Cordova) where I have a "Utils" class with various simple misc static methods.

Since this class is static, I use an `initialize()` method to pass in a few dependencies (perhaps this is not best practice, but in this single case, having this "static class" makes some things lot easier in the application.

Anyway I wish to test some of the static methods, where some may depend on these static dependencies set via the `initialize()` method.

So the Utils.initialize looks like this..

```
 export class Utils {    
   private static platform : Platform;
   private static appVersion : AppVersion;
   private static device : Device;
   private static translate : TranslateService;  

  public static initialize(appVersion : AppVersion, device : Device, platform : Platform, translate : TranslateService){
        Utils.appVersion = appVersion;
        Utils.device = device;
        Utils.platform = platform;
        Utils.translate = translate;    
      }
```

and the call to one of the methods that uses the `translate`

```
    public static compareNoCase(s1 : string, s2 : string) : number {
        ....    
        return s1.localeCompare(s2, Utils.translate.currentLang, {'sensitivity': 'base'});
      }
```

In this case, I pass in a Translate service where some string compares call use a property `language` in this translate server as above. I mock the TranslateService` as follows:

```
export class TranslateServiceMock {
  public currentLang: string = "en";
}
```

I can get this to work by using the following:

```
    describe('Test Compare String IgnoreCase', () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
          language
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            providers: [
              { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceMock },
            ],
           }).compileComponents();     
        });

        it('Expected AAAA < bbbb', inject([TranslateService], trans => {
          Utils.initialise(new AppVersion(), new Device(), new Platform(), trans);
          let r = Utils.compareNoCase("AAAA", "bbbb");
          expect(r).toEqual(-1);
        }));
```

However, using the above, I need to pass the line `Utils.initialise(new AppVersion(), new Device(), new Platform(), trans);` into each `it` block.

I was hoping to be ale to do this "static initialization" in the `beforeEach()`, so I tried the following, where I do the initialization in the `then()` of the promise returned from the call to `compileComponents()`....

```
    describe('Test Compare String IgnoreCase', () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {             
          TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            providers: [
              { provide: TranslateService, useClass: TranslateServiceMock },
            ],
           }).compileComponents()
          .then(_ => {
             inject([TranslateService], trans => {
               Utils.initialise(new AppVersion(), new Device(), new Platform(), trans)
             });
          });
        });

        it('Expected AAAA < bbbb', inject([TranslateService], trans => {     
          let r = Utils.compareNoCase("AAAA", "bbbb");
          expect(r).toEqual(-1);
        }));
```

but when I use the above the static property the method under test is accessing, ie the static reference of the translate service that is passed in via `initialize()`, is null.

Is there a way to do this "static initialization", or do I just have to include it in each test as in the first snippet?

Comment: do you mean this **how to use access readonly constants inside spec file?**

Comment: @Aravind  I've added more more sample code in the question to show exactly the method and the static property it calls.